# What does write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0x10000) do?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I searched the web a lot but didn't find a short explanation about what `write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0x10000)` really do. It is related to the Linux kernel and I curios about developing LKM's. I want to know what this really do and what are the security issues with this.

**It used to remove the write protection on the syscall table.**
**But how it is really works? and what does each thing in this line?**

Comment: What architecture you are talking about? What documentation you have read? Does it say what bit 16 is for?

Comment: For next time, you should add kernel version, file and line number, so we can help better (maybe also a link to e.g. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source [which I recommend you to use, to understand quickly kernel structure])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CR0 is one of the *control registers* available on x86 CPUs, which contains flags controlling CPU features related to memory protection, multitasking, paging, etc.  You can find a full description in Volume 3, Section 2.5 of [Intel's Software Developer's Manual](https://software.intel.com/content/dam/develop/public/us/en/documents/325384-sdm-vol-3abcd.pdf).

These registers are accessed by special instructions that the compiler doesn't normally generate, so `read_cr0()` is a function which executes the instruction to read this register (via inline assembly) and returns the result in a general-purpose register.  Likewise, `write_cr0()` writes to this register.

The function calls are likely to be inlined, so that the generated code would be something like

```
mov eax, cr0
or eax, 0x10000
mov cr0, eax
```

The OR with  `0x10000` sets bit 16, the Write Protect bit.  On early 32-bit x86 CPUs, code running at supervisor level (like the kernel) was always allowed to write all of virtual memory, regardless of whether the page was marked read-only.  This bit makes that optional, so that when it is set, such accesses will cause page faults.  This line of code probably follows an earlier line which temporarily cleared the bit.

Comment: Note: `write_cr0` is a wrapper: on virtual machines it has a different meaning, on real CPU, it calls `native_write_cr0` which it is not an inline function (in any case using CR register is already slow).